# SSIS - Error when passing object from one script task to another

Tags: ssis

I am passing object of a class from one script task to another. I have declared a package level variable by the name IPSService which is of type object.
The first script task contains the following piece of code

```
IPSService iPSService = new IPSService();
Dts.Variables["IPSService"].Value = iPSService;
```

I get an exception at the second line of code where the assignment happens.

The error message is as follows.

he element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.

Could somebody tell me what the issue is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to the variable like this, notice the use of `User::` in the variable name:

```
Dts.Variables["User::IPSService"].Value = iPSService;
```